# Android Studio Kotlin Autocompletion duplicate suggestions

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, rx-java2

Does somebody know why i get redundant autocompletion suggestions in AS for kotlin, see:

[image: Rx BiFunction Kotlin]

Is it possible that Android Studio shows me the Java and Kotlin suggestions also the SAM overload param will be shown additionally?

Because iam kind of new with Kotlin i have only seen so far in Java:

[image: RxJava BiFunction Java]

I just ask because i would like to know why in Kotlin it looks like repetitive suggestion and the ones with function param are also new for me.

Comment: They are all different in terms of what package they are from (java.util or io.reactivex...) and what arguments they take. As for RxKotlin, you can commonly see two similar functions where one takes a lambda argument and another takes in a normal object parameter. They are basically the same.

Comment: But for instance: `BiFunction(function: (T1,T2) -> R)` and both are from `io.reactivex.functions` so that´s the reason why iam a bit confused, because it seems to be like a duplicate somehow

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a problem here. They are either different functions altogether, or from Java or reactivex. Which function do you see as a duplicate?